# Linux implementation of VISA API

Tags: linux, visa

Do you know any Linux implementations of [Virtual Instrument Software Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Instrument_Software_Architecture)? Even simple and restricted? Free and open-source implementations are preferred.

Only implementation I know is [NI VISA](http://www.ni.com/visa/) which is non-free and closed-source. Moreover, it runs on very limited number of Linux distributions. I don't know whether it is possible to run it on Debian, for instance.

Thanks.

Comment: If you need it to control a gpib device, check out [linux-gpib](http://linux-gpib.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 4):

Well, what do you need it to do?  I have been working on a pure Python instrument library that can communicate over several different protocols (serial, VXI-11 (LXI), GPIB (linux-gpib), and PyVISA) called python-ivi, located here: http://www.github.com/alexforencich/python-ivi .  It is an interpretation of the Interchangeable Virtual Instruments specification.  It's not VISA, though, so if you specifically need VISA, it's not going to help you.

It's written in python 3 and tested in linux, but it should be cross-platform as it is pure python.  The implementation of VXI-11 in python-vxi11 is also pure python and therefore should also be cross-platform.

The project is still in relatively early development in terms of the higher-level drivers and abstractions, but it does basically everything PyVISA does for low-level interfacing.

Comment: I'm not familiar with IVI. Isn't it based on COM interfaces and thus is not cross-platform?

Comment: Basically, python-ivi is a Pythonized interpretation of the API specified in the IVI standards documentation.  It's not an implementation, because IVI only supports .NET and COM classes.  The goal of python-ivi is not to enable use of existing IVI drivers, but to provide standard framework for writing pure Python drivers.  See the Github page for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Googling this for a bit only yields the 7 year old (2005) Open Visa which I haven't tried.

NI VISA is tricky to get to work with Debian and Ubuntu, but I have seen post with people claiming success at least for kernels before 3.x see eg:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1665036
and
https://decibel.ni.com/content/thread/7232

Good luck to you. I will probably try Open Visa and perhaps give NI VISA a shot and report back if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of PyVisa? It's an open source, cross-platform VISA implementation written in/for Python.

http://pyvisa.sourceforge.net/

It seems to rely on a VISA dynamically-linked library coming with your equipment
(see here: http://pyvisa.sourceforge.net/vpp43.html#about-the-vpp43-module)
so it may not solve your problem, but it's worth a look.

Comment: PyVisa is a binding between Python and VISA, correct? I need VISA itself.

Comment: Yeah, it's just a binding. There are some Linux instrumentation examples here (http://www.home.agilent.com/agilent/editorial.jspx?cc=US&lc=eng&ckey=1189290&nid=-34952.0.00&id=1189290&cmpid=20586), but, again, this is not VISA for linux. Might be a work around though. The examples show communication via TCPIP and SCPI, among other things.

Comment: PyVisa provides bindings to NI-VISA and _also_ works with the [PyVISA-py](https://pyvisa-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) provider. If Python is your thing, this may work for you.

Comment: @bfris You should create another answer. I think PyVISA-py is what the OP is looking for.